# ConnectionString for connecting to SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, connection-string

I have an application (WinForms) which using SQL Server as its database.

Now I am using `app.config` file to access `ConnectionString`.

Have a look at my `app.config` file

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=abc-79f1f531c9f;Initial Catalog=ItemStockInParth;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You can see that `Data Source=abc-79f1f531c9f`.

Here ==> `abc-79f1f531c9f` is server name which is running on my (Developer's) PC.

Now when application is being installed at client's site, the server name should be changed to the server name which is running on the client machine or server name which will client machine use.

Then what should be the best criteria for handling this situation?

Means I have to create one new form which asking user to enter their `Server Name` and as per that I creating our ConnectionString?

Or dynamically getting the `servername`?

Or just hard-code the `Server Name` of client machine (or server name which will client machine use) inside our `App.config` file?

please help.....

Comment: Is the SQL Server preinstalled on the client machine? Or, is the SQL Server installed on the client at the same time your software is deployed?

Comment: i will install MSSQL Server on client machine At the time of Installing my application on client machine. [i have a single user application i have to install MSSql Server on every machine when i will install my Applicaiton]

Comment: If you manually go through the hassle of a SQL Server install, then I don't see a reason not to copy the new SQL Server instance name into your app.config.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to provide a place where the user can enter the name of the server, or if you are clever, provide a list of available servers on the network (for example by using the code referenced by @user350374).  Then you can generate an appropriate connection string as you need it using the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = ##SERVER NAME FROM USER##
builder.InitialCatalog = "ItemStockInParth";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
builder.Pooling = false;

string connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    // use the connection here for your code

    con.Close();
}
```

This would take the place of requesting the connection string from your configuration class, i.e., where you would normally say `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings['dbConnectionString'].ConnectionString`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. and BTW what should be the best way for moving DataBase from Developers server to Server which Client Machine will use?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can programmatically read the list of connectionstrings defined in the app.config, I suggest you create a list of connection strings and ask the user which one to use:

```
foreach(ConnectionStringSettings setting in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
  ...
}
```

It's better than to ask for the server name, as you can give a nice name to a connectionstring entry.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for
http://krishnapyrmca.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/get-sql-server-name-using-c/

Comment: Creating `ConnectionString` Dynamically using this kind of C# code is only solution of is there any better solution?  Thank you so much for answering

Answer (score 0):

```
<add key="Connectionstring" value="Data Source=.;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppData.mdf;
    Initial Catalog=Appdata;Integrated Security=True"/>
<add key="Connectionstring" value="Data Source=.;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppData.mdf;
    Initial Catalog=Appdata;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Simply add this code in the `app.config` file and attach your database to the setup file.
It automatically takes the database from the setup file of your project.